# Swift for in loop. Constant or variable?

Tags: swift, variables, constants

Apple in their documentation says

```
for index in 1...5 {
   print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
}
```

“In the example above, index is a constant whose value is automatically set at the start of each iteration of the loop. As such, index does not have to be declared before it is used. It is implicitly declared simply by its inclusion in the loop declaration, without the need for a let declaration keyword.

”

Why do they call index a constant if it's value changes inside the loop ?

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.2)”. Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/ru/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-2/id881256329?l=en

Comment: It is redeclared for each iteration so it’s a new constant with the same name

Answer (score 2):

It's a constant because you can't change it inside the loop. The compiler translates the for loop to something to the effect of:

```
var iterator = (1...5).makeIterator()
while true {
    if let index = iterator.next() {
        // the loop body goes here
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

`index` is constant, but a new `index` gets declared every iteration.

Comment: `while let index = iterator.next() { ... }`

Comment: @MartinR yes, I know. I deliberately rewrote differently it to illustrate the point that index is declared inside the loop.